# Compare files with different encoding

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, diff, iso-8859-2

Few months ago i was trying to move old php4 and iso8859-2 based system on php5 and utf8 encoding. Everything works good but now need to finally run this new version and the problem is that in the past months in the old system some changes ware been made and i need to have actual version on this php5 based system.
I wanted to compare those two systems with KDiff3 but, because of encoding diffs he told me that there are 2300 differences.
The best solutions would be to use some tool to compare without this encoding changes.
Is there a tool to compare two different encoded files like their ware the same encoding?

Sorry if my post is confusing but i've tried to explain as simply as i see it.

Answer (score 2):

It works in in Beyond Compare 4.0 if you uncheck the "Compare file size" checkbox and use "Rules-based comparison" in the Session Settings.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t.  You upgrade the legacy encoding to UTF-8 and then compare those.

Comment: indeed, and any correct visual diff tool will do that internally, at most with just a selection of the right encoding on the old folder (UTF8 is quite easy to detect)

Answer (score 0):

Our product, [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com), can compare files with different character encodings and will ignore those differences.  It will even automatically detect different encodings, so it should work out of the box.

Comment: How can I set BeyondCompare to use Latin1 or iso-8859-1

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude Just below each file's path edit is a panel with the file's last modified time, size, encoding, and line endings.  If you click the one for the encoding (usually it'll say "ANSI"), there will be a dropdown to select a different encoding.  If you want it to affect all files of a specific type, click the "Format" button on the toolbar and chance the "Encoding" combobox in the "Conversion" tab of the resulting dialog.  There are some additional ways for special cases, but those would be easier to describe if you email support@scootersoftware.com.